# How many distinct colorings (black or white) of an 8x8 chessboard be made? Provided rotation is allowed.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, statistics, combinations

> Let $C$ denote the set of colorings of an 8x8 chessboard, where each square is colored either black or white. Let $\sim$ denote the equivalence relation on $C$ defined as follows:
>
> two colorings are equivalent if and only if one of them can be obtained from the other by a rotation of the chessboard. What is the cardinality of the set $C/\sim$ of the equivalence classes of elements of $C $ under $\sim$ ?

***METHOD 1(A TIRESOME PROCESS)***
Let us start with boards having lesser number of squares:

1. If the board is 1x1 then we don't have to think, the answer is simply 1
2. Let us consider a 2x2 board (say) $$A=\begin{pmatrix}*&*\\ * &*\end{pmatrix}$$ there are a total of $2^4=16$ ways to color the 4 squares in our board A.

I will list down the ways in which we can color the square such that on rotation of kind $0^0,90^0,180^0,and\ 270^0$ counterclockwise we get an equivalent coloring configuration.

*Before that there are a few Notations I'll use*

- *I'll use '$' to represent* ***Black colored squares***, *and*
- '*' *to represent* ***White colored squares***

**Category 1**
$$\begin{pmatrix}*&*\\*&*\end{pmatrix}$$ there is only one such coloring and it can be obtained through any type of rotation
**Category 2**
$$\begin{pmatrix}$&$\\$&$\end{pmatrix}$$ similar to catagory 1 there is only one such coloring and it can be obtained through any type of rotation
**Category 3**
$$\begin{pmatrix}$&*\\*&*\end{pmatrix}$$ there are 4 such coloring (one black 3 white) which can be obtained from the given configuration by rotation.
**Category 4**
$$\begin{pmatrix}*&$\\$&$\end{pmatrix}$$ there are 4 such coloring (one white 3 black) which can be obtained from the given configuration by rotation.
**Category 5**
$$\begin{pmatrix}*&$\\$&*\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$\begin{pmatrix}$&*\\*&$\end{pmatrix}$$
they are two rotations of each other with coloring(2 black and 2 white diagonal).
**Category 6**
$$\begin{pmatrix}*&*\\$&$\end{pmatrix}$$ there are 4 such colorings (2 black 2 white parallelly) which again can be obtained from rotation.

Observe: No coloring category(i) can be obtained by rotating category(j)  configuration ($i\neq j$)

Each Category is an equivalence class as defined in question

***METHOD 2(BURNSIDE'S LEMMA): on 2x2 chessboard***

> BURNSIDE'S LEMMA:G be a finite group of permutations on a set S, then the number of orbits of elements of S under G is $$\frac{\sum_{\phi \in G}|fix\phi|}{|G|}$$

Applying this lemma to Category 1,2,3,4 we obtain that the number of such distinct colorings(rotation allowed) is merely 1 for each case.

For Category 5 and 6 together (i.e. coloring 2 of the squares black and two white)
the following table justifies my answer
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline elements\ of\ Z_4 & numbers\ of\ colorings\ that\ are\ fixed\ \\ \hline identity=0^0 & 6 \\ \hline 90^0 or\ 270^0 & 0 \\ \hline 180^0  & 2 \\ \hline  \end{array}

hence, number of distinct colorings(rotation allowed) of a 2x2 chessboard when two squares are colored black and two white is $\frac{6+2.0+2}{4}=2$

So, in all there are 1+1+1+1+2=6 equivalence classes of the set C(set of colorings of 2x2 chessboard) under $\sim$

*I understand that the process I'm using in Method 1 is tiring and time consuming. I got the hint from the comments that we can use Burnside's Lemma to do the problem, so I used it on 2x2 chessboard in Method 2, but how to determine the Set of Colorings of the huge 8x8 chessboard on which I will have to act the group $Z_4$ ?*

Comment: It seems this question is too advanced for you.  (This is based on "I cannot think of any way how to do it")

Comment: Do you know and understand the [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma)?

Comment: Just a reminder: take a look at our guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [avoiding "I cannot think of any way"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) questions.

Comment: Here's a list of links to questions relating to Burnside's lemma. Maybe your question will be there, or maybe reading some of those will help you understand it better. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions/13335#13335

Comment: Here's one that is somewhat similar: how many ways are there to have an $n×n$ board with 2 black squares and $n^2-2$ white squares? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744161/counting-shaded-squares/744383#744383

Comment: Regarding your question “how to determine the Set of rotational symmetries of the huge 8x8 chessboard”:  An 8×8 chessboard has the same four rotational symmetries as any other size chessboard or any square at all: you can rotate it by 0°, 90°, 180°, or 270°. This is all that matters for Burnside's lemma.

Comment: @MJD I was wrong to write *Set of Rotational symmetries* I have changed it to *Set of Colorings*

Comment: You can use combinatoric techniques to count the colorings without listimg them one at a time. For example, how many colorings are there in all? It's $2^{64}$.  Do check out that chessboard one I linked above, I think you will find it helpful. Your question is somewhat easier because it doesn't have the extra constaint of requiring exactly two black squares.

Comment: @MJD that link helped a lot understand it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

We will categorize chessboards based on whether they have $1$-fold, $2$-fold, or $4$-fold rotational symmetry. Let $C(n)$ denote the chessboards with $n$-fold symmetry, and let $C’(n)$ denote chessboards with highest order $n$-fold rotational symmetry. Boards in $C(n)$ are uniquely determined by $\frac{64}{n}$ chess board tiles, so $|C(n)|=2^{\frac{64}{n}}$. Boards with highest order $4$-fold symmetry are just $C’(4)=C(4)$, Boards with highest order $2$-fold symmetry are given by $C’(2)=C(2)-C(4)$, while boards with highest order $1$-fold symmetry are given by $C’(1)=C(1)-C(2)$. And lastly,
$$|C’(n)/{\sim}|=\frac{n|C’(n)|}{4}.$$
Then,
$$|C/{\sim}|=|C’(1)/{\sim}|+ |C’(2)/{\sim}|+ |C’(4)/{\sim}|\\ =\frac{|C’(1)|}{4}+\frac{|C’(2)|}{2}+|C’(4)|\\ = \frac{|C(1)|-|C(2)|}{4}+\frac{|C(2)|-|C(4)|}{2}+|C(4)|\\ = \frac{|C(1)|}{4}+\frac{|C(2)|}{4}+\frac{|C(4)|}{2}\\ = 2^{62}+2^{30}+2^{15} $$

Comment: I didn't understand the terms like n-fold rotational symmetry, order of n-fold rotational symmetries, and please provide a source of the fact that C(n) is determined by $\frac{64}{n}$ chessboard tiles

Comment: @Chayan $n$-fold rotational symmetry means that the board is invariant under rotation by $2\pi/n$ (c.f. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_symmetry). It follows that a board with $n$-fold rotational symmetry has $n$ Identical parts that are rotated $2\pi/n$ from each other, so you get a unique board with $n$-fold symmetry by changing the makeup of that rotated part. There are $n$ identical parts, and hence each individual part is made up of $64/n$ tiles, and therefore there are $2^{64/n}$ such choices for the rotated part.

Comment: @Chayan Highest order $n$ fold rotational symmetry means, that it has $n$-fold rotational symmetry and no higher degree of rotational symmetry. For example, a square has $1$-fold, $2$-fold, and $4$-fold rotational symmetry, but it’s highest order is $4$-fold.