# Find the number of all subsets of $\{1, 2, \ldots,2015\}$ with $n$ elements such that the sum of the elements in the subset is divisible by 5

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, generating-functions

The problem is as in the question title. Only one addition - $n$ is not divisible by $5$.

I already have a solution involving permutations, but recently I read about generating functions and I was wondering if this problem can be solved with them.

A similar problem is the following:
Find the number of all subsets of $\{1, 2, \ldots, 2015\}$ and the sum of elements in each subset is divisible by 5. The generating function used is $${((1+x^0)(1+x^1)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)(1+x^4))}^{403}.$$

But this function cannot be used for my problem, since we need to count how many elements have been "used" to make the subset. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A generating function solution.

For every $S\subset\{1,2,\ldots,2015\}$ we will write $\Sigma S=\sum_{k\in S}k$.

Let
$$
f(a,x) = \prod_{k=1}^{2015} (1+a^kx) =
\sum_{S\subset\{1,\ldots,2015\}} a^{\Sigma S} x^{|S|}.
$$
Take the average this function over putting $5$th complex roots of unity for $a$. Let $\omega=e^{2\pi i/5}$; then
$$
\frac15\sum_{j=0}^4 f(\omega^j,x) = 
\sum_{S\subset\{1,\ldots,2015\}} \left(\frac15\sum_{j=0}^4 \big(\omega^{\Sigma S}\big)^j\right) x^{|S|} =
\sum_{\substack{S\subset\{1,\ldots,2015\}\\\Sigma S\equiv0\pmod5}} x^{|S|}.
\tag{$*$}
$$
On the RHS of $(*)$, the coefficient of $x^n$ is the number of $n$-element sets $S\subset\{1,\ldots,2015\}$ with $\Sigma S\equiv0\pmod5$.

On the other hand,
$$
f(\omega^j,x)= \begin{cases} (1+x)^{2015} & \text{if } j=0 \\
(1+x^5)^{403} & \text{if } j=1,2,3,4 \end{cases}
$$
so on the LHS of $(*)$ the coefficient of $x^n$ is: $\frac15\binom{2015}n$ if $n$ is co-prime with $5$, and
$\frac15\binom{2015}n+\frac45\binom{403}{n/5}$ if $5|n$.

Comment: Instructive and straight forward. Very nice! (+1)

Comment: Definitely the answer I was looking for! Simple and well explained.

Comment: @user141614 I will most likely award the bounty here. I have added a special case to my discussion so as not to create the impression that PET would not yield the formula you propose. This special case is when $q$ is a multiple of $k$ and $k$ is prime. You are cordially invited to consult these remarks.

Answer (score 7):

This  is  a  straightforward  application  of  the  Polya  Enumeration
Theorem. We treat the problem of  subsets with $n$ elements of the set
$\{1,2,\ldots, q\}$ whose sum is divisible by $k.$ Suppose $Z(P_n)$ is
the cycle index  of the set operator $\mathfrak{P}_{=n}$  given by the
recurrence by Lovasz which is

$$Z(P_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=1}^n (-1)^{l+1} a_l Z(P_{n-l})
\quad\text{where}\quad
Z(P_0) = 1.$$

We obtain  by PET the following  formula for the OGF  of ordinary sets

$$Z(P_n)\left(w+w^2+\cdots+w^q\right)
= Z(P_n)\left(\sum_{m=1}^q w^m\right).$$

With $\rho$ a root of unity namely
$$\rho = \exp(2\pi i/k)$$

we get for the desired count the value
$$\frac{1}{k} 
\left.\sum_{p=0}^{k-1} 
Z(P_n)\left(\sum_{m=1}^q w^m\right)\right|_{w=\rho^p}.$$

We will compute  the value for $p=0$ separately and  to do this recall
the OGF of the set operator $\mathfrak{P}_{=n}$ which is

$$Z(P_n) = [z^n]
\exp\left(a_1 z - a_2 \frac{z^2}{2}
+ a_3 \frac{z^3}{3}
- a_4 \frac{z^4}{4}
+\cdots \right).$$

or

$$Z(P_n) = 
[z^n] \exp\left(\sum_{r\ge 1} (-1)^{r+1} a_r \frac{z^r}{r}\right).$$

On substituting this into our formula we get

$$\frac{1}{k} 
\sum_{p=0}^{k-1} 
\left. [z^n] 
\exp\left(\sum_{r\ge 1} (-1)^{r+1} \frac{z^r}{r}
\sum_{m=1}^q w^{rm} \right) \right|_{w=\rho^p}.$$

When $p=0$ we obtain
$$\frac{1}{k} 
[z^n] \exp\left(q\sum_{r\ge 1} (-1)^{r+1} \frac{z^r}{r}\right)
= \frac{1}{k} 
[z^n] \exp\left(q \log (1+z)\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{k} [z^n] (1+z)^q
= \frac{1}{k} {q\choose n}.$$

We switch to *algorithmics* for the remainder of this discussion.

In treating  the case $p\ge  1$ we make the  following observation.
When substituting into  the terms of the cycle  index those $a_r$ from
the product  where $pr$  is a  multiple of $k$  produce the  value $q$
while the remaining $a_r$ create a sequence of period $k$ that depends
only on  the remainder $b$  when $q$ is  divided by $k$ where  we take
$1\le b\le k.$

This yields  an algorithm  where we iterate  over the  cycle index,
extract eventual powers of $q$ from the terms and interpolate the rest
in terms  of $b.$ The  algorithm can be  used to compute  formulae for
fixed  combinations  of  $n$  and  $k$  like the  ones  at  this  [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556924/) automatically.

We obtain for $(n,k) = (3,3)$
$$1/18\,{q}^{3}+1/3\,{b}^{2}-1/6\,{q}^{2}-{\frac {11\,b}{9}}+q/3+2/3$$
and sure enough comparing it to the link these are the right values.

Supposing now  that we  are interested in  divisibility by  five of
three-element subsets i.e. the pair $(n,k) = (3,5)$ we find

$$1/12\,{b}^{4}-{\frac {13\,{b}^{3}}{15}}+1/30\,{q}^{3}+{\frac {
181\,{b}^{2}}{60}}-1/10\,{q}^{2}-{\frac {127\,b}{30}}+q/15+2$$

which gives the sequence (starting at $q=3$)

$$0, 0, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 24, 33, 44, 57, 72, 91, \ldots$$

For the pair $(11,5)$ we obtain

$${\frac {{q}^{11}}{199584000}}-{\frac {{q}^{10}}{3628800}}+{
\frac {{q}^{9}}{151200}}-{\frac {11\,{q}^{8}}{120960}}+{\frac {
683\,{q}^{7}}{864000}}+{\frac {{b}^{4}{q}^{2}}{1200}}\\-{\frac {
781\,{q}^{6}}{172800}}-{\frac {{b}^{4}q}{80}}-{\frac {{b}^{3}{q
}^{2}}{120}}+{\frac {31063\,{q}^{5}}{1814400}}+1/24\,{b}^{4}+1/
8\,{b}^{3}q+{\frac {7\,{b}^{2}{q}^{2}}{240}}\\-{\frac {1529\,{q}^
{4}}{36288}}-{\frac {631\,{b}^{3}}{1500}}-{\frac {859\,{b}^{2}q
}{2000}}-{\frac {137\,b{q}^{2}}{3000}}+{\frac {16103\,{q}^{3}}{
252000}}+{\frac {863\,{b}^{2}}{600}}\\+{\frac {129\,bq}{200}}-{
\frac {419\,{q}^{2}}{12600}}-{\frac {25\,b}{12}}-{\frac {31\,q
}{110}}+1$$

which gives the sequence (starting at $q=11$)

$$0, 2, 15, 72, 273, 873, 2474, 6363, 15114, 33592, \ldots.$$

Another interesting pair is $(3,6)$ which gives

$$-{\frac {{b}^{5}q}{90}}-{\frac {{b}^{5}}{90}}+{\frac {7\,{b}^{4
}q}{36}}+1/4\,{b}^{4}-{\frac {23\,{b}^{3}q}{18}}-2\,{b}^{3}+{
\frac {35\,{b}^{2}q}{9}}\\+1/36\,{q}^{3}+7\,{b}^{2}-{\frac {242\,
bq}{45}}-1/12\,{q}^{2}-{\frac {313\,b}{30}}+{\frac {17\,q}{6}}+5$$

and $(4,7)$ which produces

$${\frac {{b}^{6}}{360}}-{\frac {3\,{b}^{5}}{40}}+{\frac {389\,{b
}^{4}}{504}}+{\frac {{q}^{4}}{168}}-{\frac {215\,{b}^{3}}{56}}-
1/28\,{q}^{3}\\+{\frac {3041\,{b}^{2}}{315}}+{\frac {11\,{q}^{2}
}{168}}-{\frac {403\,b}{35}}-q/28+5.$$

The  Maple code  for this  including a  total enumeration  routine for
verification and some code to  prettify the formulae for $k$ small was
as follows.

```
with(combinat);

pet_cycleind_set :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add((-1)^(l+1)*a[l]*pet_cycleind_set(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_flatten_term :=
proc(varp)
local terml, d, cf, v;

    terml := [];

    cf := varp;
    for v in indets(varp) do
        d := degree(varp, v);
        terml := [op(terml), seq(v, k=1..d)];
        cf := cf/v^d;
    od;

    [cf, terml];
end;

V :=
proc(q, n, k)
    local comb, res;
    option remember;

    res := 0;
    comb := firstcomb(q, n);

    while type(comb, set) do
        if add(p, p in comb) mod k = 0 then
            res := res + 1;
        fi;

        comb := nextcomb(comb, q);
    od;

    res;
end;

CF :=
proc(n, k)
    local term, rho, res, p, flat, ixvar, rmd, m,
    rep, qpow, w, ex, vals, val;
    option remember;

    res := 0; rho := exp(2*Pi*I/k);

    for term in pet_cycleind_set(n) do
        flat := pet_flatten_term(term);

        for p to k-1 do
            vals := []; rep := []; qpow := 0;

            for ixvar in flat[2] do
                ex := p*op(1, ixvar);

                if ex mod k = 0 then
                    qpow := qpow + 1;
                else
                    rep := [op(rep), ixvar];
                fi;
            od;


            for rmd to k do
                val := 1;

                for ixvar in rep do
                    ex := p*op(1, ixvar);
                    val := val * add(w^(ex*m), m=1..rmd);
                od;

                vals :=
                [op(vals), subs(w=rho, expand(val))];
            od;

            res := res + flat[1]*q^qpow *
            interp([seq(b, b=1..k)], vals, b);
        od;
    od;

    binomial(q,n)/k + res/k;
end;

CFsimp :=
proc(n, k)
    local form, res, term, lcf, cnst;
    option remember;

    form := collect(expand(CF(n,k)), {b,q}, `distributed`);

    cnst := coeff(coeff(form, b, 0), q, 0);

    res := 0;

    for term in form-cnst do
        lcf := lcoeff(term);

        res := res +
        simplify(Re(lcf))*term/lcf;
    od;

    res + simplify(cnst);
end;

F :=
proc(qv, n, k)
local bv;

    if qv mod k = 0 then
        bv := k;
    else
        bv := qv mod k;
    fi;

    subs({q=qv, b=bv}, CFsimp(n,k));
end;
```

The reader  is invited to  contribute a better  simplification routine
making more effective  use of the mathematical givens.  The Maple code
should be considered betaware.

**Remark  Sat Jan 23  2016.** I  present one  of the  special cases
where radical simplification is possible. Start from the formula

$$\frac{1}{k} {q\choose n} +
\frac{1}{k} 
\sum_{p=1}^{k-1} 
\left. [z^n] 
\exp\left(\sum_{r\ge 1} (-1)^{r+1} \frac{z^r}{r}
\sum_{m=1}^q w^{rm} \right) \right|_{w=\rho^p}.$$

Now  suppose  that  $q$ is  a  multiple  of  $k$  and  $k$ is  an  odd
prime.  Observe  that the  sum  $$\sum_{m=1}^q  w^{rm}$$  is equal  to
$q/k\times k = q$ if $pr$ is a multiple of $k$ and zero otherwise. But
$pr$ can only be  a multiple of $k$ if $r$ is  a multiple of $k.$ This
yields

$$\frac{1}{k} {q\choose n} +
\frac{1}{k} 
\sum_{p=1}^{k-1} 
\left. [z^n] 
\exp\left(\sum_{r\ge 1} (-1)^{kr+1} \frac{z^{kr}}{kr}
\sum_{m=1}^q w^{krm} \right) \right|_{w=\rho^p}
\\ = \frac{1}{k} {q\choose n} +
\frac{1}{k} 
\sum_{p=1}^{k-1} 
\left. [z^n] 
\exp\left(\sum_{r\ge 1} (-1)^{kr+1} \frac{z^{kr}}{kr}
\frac{q}{k}\times k \right) \right|_{w=\rho^p}
\\ = \frac{1}{k} {q\choose n} +
\frac{1}{k} 
\sum_{p=1}^{k-1} 
[z^n] 
\exp\left(\frac{q}{k}
\sum_{r\ge 1} (-1)^{kr+1} \frac{z^{kr}}{r}\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{k} {q\choose n} +
\frac{1}{k} 
\sum_{p=1}^{k-1} 
[z^n] 
\exp\left(-\frac{q}{k}
\sum_{r\ge 1} \frac{(-z)^{kr}}{r}\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{k} {q\choose n} +
\frac{1}{k} 
\sum_{p=1}^{k-1} 
[z^n] 
\exp\left(-\frac{q}{k} \log\frac{1}{1-(-z)^k}\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{k} {q\choose n} +
\frac{1}{k} 
\sum_{p=1}^{k-1} 
[z^n] (1+z^k)^{q/k}.$$

Therefore if $n$ is coprime to $k$ we obtain
$$\frac{1}{k} {q\choose n}$$

and if it is a multiple of $k$

$$\frac{1}{k} {q\choose n} +
\frac{k-1}{k} {q/k\choose n/k}.$$

Comment: Instructive approach! (+1)

Comment: Thank you for the kind remark. What I have here is not as simple as it could be but it features a variant of the exponential formula which I present frequently in order to encourage its use. This formula is central to combinatorics, producing e.g. a variety of statistics on random permutations.

Comment: Your answers look indeed sometimes complicated. But, nevertheless most of them are worth to read and analyse it. I'm awaiting to see more of your applications of the exponential formula!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $\frac{1}{5}\binom{2015}{n}$.

For each subset of $n$ elements (not necessarily with sum multiple of $5$) consider the set of the translations of the $n$-set. In other words, if we have $\{a_1,a_2\dots a_n\}$ Consider the family of sets of the form $\{r(a_1+k),r(a_2+k),\dots r(a_3+k)\}$ with $k\in\{0,1,\dots 2015\}$, and where $r(m)$ is simply the smallest positive integer congruent to $m\bmod 2015$.

By considering the equivalence relation of translation we split the $n-sets$ into some families,in each exactly one fifth of the subsets have sum multiple of $5$.

Comment: Thank you. The solution is interesting. But as I have said in my question, I'm interested whether the problem can be solved using generating functions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews are you talking to me? I think in the solution I use that $n$ and $5$ be coprime.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you are right ! It should be better now ! If not I can try to fix it tomorrow as it's quite late now

Comment: Seems right now, even if the last step is a bit hand-wavy.