# counting 11-element subsets of {1, 2, ..., n} with sum divisible by 5

Tags: combinatorics

What possibly easy ways are there to count the number of subsets of $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$ with $11$ elements, sum of which is divisible by $5$?

I started with making smaller subsets out of $\{6, 7, ..., n\}$ and then adding the remainder-correcting number(s) from  $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, but this approach leads to complications of its own. So any idea?

Comment: I assume for large $n$ the value is close to $\frac{n\choose{11}}{5}$

Comment: There was an extensive discussion of this problem with different users participating at the following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618420/).

Comment: @Guy Yeah I agree. Is the formula generally true for when n is a multiple of 5?

Comment: @Sajad if you follow the link Marko posted, you will find the exact formulas for $(5,n)=1$ and $5|n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function
$$f(x,t)=\prod_{i=1}^n(1+xt^n).$$
The $x^at^b$ coefficient here is the number of $a$-element
subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with sum $b$. To sieve out those
sets which are multiples of $5$ consider
$$g(x)=\frac{f(x,1)+f(x,\zeta)+f(x,\zeta^2)+f(x,\zeta^3)+f(x,\zeta^4)}5$$
with $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/5)$. The coefficient of $x^a$ in $g(x)$
is the number of $a$ element subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ which
sum to a multiple of $5$.

Obviously
$$f(x,1)=(1+x)^n.$$
If $n=5r+q$ with $0\le q\le1$ then
$$f(x,\zeta^k)=(1+x^5)^r\prod_{j=1}^q(1+x\zeta^k)$$
for $k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. You'll need to treat the values of $q$ individually.